# How to install my app in windows phone 10

Tags: insider-preview, side-loading

I had a file app.xap when I click on the file it is showing the dialog box for install.But,when I click on the install it is not showing any installation process.Please suggest me.How to install the app in my windows 10 phone.

Comment: Is your phone in Developer mode? Also, you should use the `insider-preview` tag, not `windows-10`, for stuff about Windows 10 Mobile.

Comment: @CBHacking As an aside, although you currently need [more rep for edits](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to be applied immediately, you can still propose an edit to correct tags, and if those edits are accepted, you are awarded rep. The original poster is also informed of the proposed edit, and asked to review it.

Comment: Ah, thanks Rowland. I'm pretty new to contributing to StackExchange.

Comment: Ah, the *rep* is why so many questions have been edited by @RowlandShaw lately! I wondered. :D

Comment: @Shawn People who self-approve edits don't earn any rep for them - i do it so it's easier for other people to find content - tags are there to help describe the type of problem; in this case, the tags didn't mention side-loading, even though that's the main focus of the question.

Comment: @CBHacking And you're doing great - thought you'd appreciate the heads up :)

Comment: @RowlandShaw Yeah, I was joking.